# Magento 2 How to save data to custom column in "admin_user" table

Tags: magento2, collection, admin-user, savedata

Hi Here I have created a extra column `school` in the table `Admin_user`. While I trying to update or save it inside a `"PLUGIN"` its giving me error.

Here is my `Plugin` code

```
class Adminsave
{
  protected $userCollectionFactory;
  public function __construct(\Magento\User\Model\ResourceModel\User\CollectionFactory $userCollectionFactory)
  {$this->userCollectionFactory = $userCollectionFactory;}
  public function aroundexecute(\Magento\User\Controller\Adminhtml\User\Save $save)
    {
       $set = $this->userCollectionFactory->create();
       $set->setUserId(3);
       $set->setSchool(5);
       $set->save();
    }
}

Error: Call to undefined method Magento\User\Model\ResourceModel\User\Collection::setUserId()
```

Where am Doing wrong? Can i get help? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved this method of saving by creating `custom collection` for the table `Admin_user` instead of default `admin_user` collection. its will work

Answer (score 0):

Collection normally contains a list of model class, in this case userCollectionFactory will contain a lost of Model user(s).

```
$collection = $this->userCollectionFactory->create();

// load a user
$myUser = $collection->addFieldToFilter('change_field_name', ['eq' => 'change_this_value'])->getFirstItem();

$myUser->setUserId(3); // change some value
$myUser->setSchool(5);  // change some value

$collection->save($myUser); // saves a model
```

Magento custom development on http://www.rosenborgsolutions.com/articles.php

Comment: Thank you @Nadeem Sayeed for replying. I tried above method, its showing `error : :findById()`

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove line `$set->setUserId(3)`
2. Edit line from `$set = $this->userCollectionFactory->create();` to `$set = $this->userCollectionFactory->create()->load(3);`

I think that should be enough.

Comment: hi @Arbab Ahmed Thank you for responce. I updated code as 
`$set = $this->userCollectionFactory->create()->load(3);                
$set->setSchool(2);
$set->save();`

Here its same `error : undefined method Magento\User\Model\ResourceModel\User\Collection::setSchool()`

Comment: @PraveenNegimani than you have to use a custom query to set data in admin_user table. If I am not wrong than admin_user doesn't have individual model like other tables in magento 2. See this url for reference: https://webkul.com/blog/magento2-write-custom-mysql-query/

Comment: Thank you @Arbab Ahmed  this method working fine.

Comment: If you find it helpful than please mark this answer correct and vote on this answer for others to get help from it. Thanks